# Convert array with triangular matrix into vector and implement linear search

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, 2d

I created a program which will generate a low triangular matrix with random numbers. 
Now I need somehow to transfer my result into vector, then use a linear search algorithm.

Here is a part of my code.

```
void lower_half(int arr[8][8], int r)
{
    int i, j;
    cout << "\n";
    for (i = 0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << " ";

        }
        cout << "\n";

    }
}
int main()
{

    int arr[8][8], i, j;
    int r = 8;




    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    {

        {
            for (int j = 0; j < r; ++j)
            arr[i][j] = (rand() % 44) + -30;

        }
    }

    lower_half(arr,  r);
    system("pause");


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: please provide example of matrix and what do you want to get in vector?

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> to_vec(int arr[8][8], int r)
{
    int i, j;
    vector<int> vec;
    for (i = 0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            vec.push_back(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return vec;
}

int index_of(vector<int> vec, int n)
{
    for (i = 0; i<vec.size(); i++)
        if (vec[i]==n)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain me the second part "index_of"?

Comment: what part do you think that needs explanation?

Comment: I will accept your answer when, I will finish my program. Actually it's a bit more complicated that that. I can post the whole code, if you are willing to help me. :)                               Basically I need to transform my matrix into vector, then I need to use user-defined  linear search algorithm. And then sort my vector with bubble search and display the result. I already implemented this sorting as a function, but in need to combine it all together. As I did not sleep much, and I am just learning C++ by myself, it's kinda difficult.

Comment: I answered your question. you can go an add another one to answers those new questions!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use int arr[8][8] in the first place? A 2D [8][8] array is the same as 1D [8*8] array. And as such you might as well use a vector in the first place:

```
int find(std::vector<int>& arr, int value)
{
    auto it = std::find(arr.begin(), arr.end(), value);
    return it == arr.end() ? -1 : &*it - &*arr.begin();
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr(64, 0); // new vector, 64 elements, initialized to 0

    for (int& a : arr) // populate array with random numbers
        a = (rand() % 44) - 30;

    int index = find(arr, 12);

    return 0;
}
```

The iterator syntax is pretty ugly, but otherwise the code works by creating a 64 element (8*8) array and populates it with random numbers - notice `for (int& a : arr)` syntax, where `int& a` is a reference to an element in `arr`.

If you can't get away from using an int [8][8], then you can use this workaround:

```
int matrix[8][8];
int* arrayPtr = (int*)matrix; // like I said, int[8][8] is the same as int[64]
                              // so treat it as an array pointer int*

std::vector<int> arr(arrayPtr, arrayPtr + 64); // treat arrayPtr as int[64]
```

If you run into trouble with indexing the array later, don't fret:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        printf("[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, arr[i*8 + j]);
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for reply. I have no idea what is better in my case. Take a look at the whole task. It's for pascal, but I writing in C++    1. creates one of these special arrays 8x8
a. diagonal matrix
b. low triangular matrix
c. high triangular matrix
d. symmetric matrix
2. fills it with random integer numbers in a range [-30..45];
3. displays the filled array;
4. transforms array into vector;
5. searches for user specified element in vector using linear search algorithm;
6. sorts vector using one of these algorithms:
a. Bubble;
b. Insertion;
c. Selection;
7. displays the sorted vector.

Comment: Is this some sort of redundant school task? std::vector works fine in such a case and it's easy to manage. The only difference is the indexing where instead of [i][j], you use [i*8 + j].

Comment: Not really, it was for pascal, but I want to do it in C++. I founded it more challenging. I already have those sorting algorithms implemented, but have no idea how to do linear search, and combine it all together. Need to sleep, but I can not until I don't finish this.  :)

Comment: If you want a completely custom linear search, then you can just treat the [8][8] matrix as an int* and iterate over it as if it were a regular array. But anyways, std::find already does linear search. So does "index_of" in hasan's answer.